# pandas set column value only for common rows with another table

Tags: pandas

**Input**

```
table 1

+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| a | b | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| x | y | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| w | q | 0 |
+---+---+---+

table 2
+---+---+
| A | B |
+---+---+
| a | b |
+---+---+
| w | q |
+---+---+
```

**Output**

```
table 1

+---+---+---+
| A | B | C |
+---+---+---+
| a | b | 1 | <-
+---+---+---+
| x | y | 0 |
+---+---+---+
| w | q | 1 | <-
+---+---+---+
```

I have two tables, I want to set column C in table 1 to 1 for all the rows in table 1 which have the same values as the rows in table 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
In [303]: df1['C'] = df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='_')['_'].eq('both').astype(int)

In [304]: df1
Out[304]:
   A  B  C
0  a  b  1
1  x  y  0
2  w  q  1
```